# Disable remaining checkboxes after checking some of them in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to disable the checkboxes when a limit of checked checkboxes have reached. I have made a function in JavaScript in which on check of two boxes the other two become disable and the value of the checked boxes comes in id="order2". But this function is not at all working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>How would you like your coffee?</p>

<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="100">With cream<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="150">With sugar<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="200">With milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="250">With tea<br>
<br>


<input type="text" id="order2" size="50">
<input type="text" id="order3" size="50">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction2() {
  var coffee = document.querySelectorAll("[name = coffee]"); // To get arrays by Attribute in query selector use [] to get arrays of the same attribute. We can also use ("input[type = checkbox]") to get arrays.
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) {
   if (coffee[i].checked) {
      txt = txt + coffee[i].value + ", ";
      document.getElementById("order2").value = "You ordered a coffee with: " + txt.slice(0, -2);
    }

    else if (coffee.length === 2) {
     coffee[i].setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5");
     document.getElementById("order3").value = "Boxes left uncheck " + i;
    }
  }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try any of the answers? Remember that you can upvote or accept them when you find that they solve your problem.

Comment: There is no need to add "please help" or similar variants to your questions. This is a form of coercive begging, and it is not appropriate for a volunteer audience.

Answer (score 1):

Make two loops. First figure out the total number of checkboxes that are checked - this will tell you whether you need to disable unchecked checkboxes. On the second loop, if a checkbox is checked, add its `value` to an array. Otherwise, the checkbox is unchecked; *if* at least 2 checkboxes are checked (identified by the previous loop), disable it.

If the user de-selects an option after hitting the limit of 2, also loop through the checkboxes and enable them all.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  const checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll("[name = coffee]")];
  const boxesChecked = checkboxes.reduce((a, b) => a + b.checked, 0);
  document.getElementById("order3").value = "Options left to choose:" + (2 - boxesChecked);
  let addedCost = 0;
  for (const checkbox of checkboxes) checkbox.disabled = false;
  for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
    if (checkbox.checked) addedCost += Number(checkbox.value);
    else if (boxesChecked === 2) checkbox.disabled = true;
  }
  document.getElementById("order2").value = "Costs: " + addedCost;
}
```

```html
<p>How would you like your coffee?</p>

<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="100">With cream<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="150">With sugar<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="200">With milk<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="250">With tea<br>
  <br>


  <input type="text" id="order2" size="50">
  <input type="text" id="order3" size="50">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to available mixing HTML with JavaScript using `onclick`. The proper way is with event listeners, for example:

```js
const myCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'); 
const myReset = document.querySelector('input[type=reset]');

myCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.addEventListener('click', checkCheckboxes));
myReset.addEventListener('click', resetCheckboxes);

function checkCheckboxes() {
  let checked = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
  if (checked.length >= 2) {
    myCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.disabled = true);
  }
}

function resetCheckboxes() {
  myCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.disabled = false);
}
```

```html
<p>How would you like your coffee?</p>

<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="100">With cream<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="150">With sugar<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="200">With milk<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="250">With tea<br>
  <br>


  <input type="text" id="order2" size="50">
  <input type="text" id="order3" size="50">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate how many are checked when they are clicked and disable the others.  Note: the better way to handle this is to use classes and toggle the class.

```js
'use strict';

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.type == 'checkbox')
    myFunction2(e);
})

function myFunction2(e) {
  const coffee = document.querySelectorAll('[name=coffee]');
  const checked = document.querySelectorAll(':checked');
  const order2 = document.querySelector('#order2');
  const order3 = document.querySelector('#order3');

  order2.value = checked.length
     ? "You ordered a coffee with: " + [...checked].map(cb => cb.value).join(', ')
     : ''
    
  if (checked.length === 2 && e.target.checked) {
    coffee.forEach(cb => {
      if (!cb.checked)
        cb.disabled = true
    });
    order3.value = "Boxes left unchecked: " + (coffee.length - checked.length);
    return false;
  }
  else
    coffee.forEach(cb=>cb.disabled=false)


  order3.value = "Boxes left unchecked: " + (coffee.length - checked.length);


}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

label>input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>How would you like your coffee?</p>

<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="100">With cream</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="150">With sugar</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="200">With milk</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="250">With tea</label>

  <input type="text" id="order2" size="50">
  <input type="text" id="order3" size="50">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```